# Syntax Error while running command from another hosts

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

I run a command to fetch server uptime as below

```
[root@localhosts ~]# printf "`uname -n`  `uptime| awk -F " " {'print $3,$4'}`\n"  
localhosts  75 days,
```

Now when I run same command from another hosts to same above linux server  "localhosts" to get same output, I get error

```
[root@master /]# ssh localhosts 'printf "`uname -n`  `uptime| awk -F " " {'print $3,$4'}`\n"'  
awk: cmd. line:1: {print  
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Do you know better way to run the command from another hosts to get similar output from the remote hosts as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh localhosts 'printf "`uname -n`  `uptime| awk -F " " {'\''print $3,$4'\''}`\n"'
```

The issue is that you had nested single quotes. That does not work well.